# Problem - Subscription Google Colab Pro "unexpected error"

Tags: google-colaboratory, subscription

I am trying to subscribe in Google Colab Pro: https://colab.research.google.com/signup

But I am getting the following error "There was an unexpected error. Try again later. [OR-FGIA-04]"

[image]

When I click in details, I get the following:

[image]

Does anyone know what is happening? I tried to subcribe from different Google accounts, browsers and computers but it does not work at all.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience you need to have a valid payment method (e.g. credit card) preset in your Google account.